# ffmpeg subprocess fail to open on OS X

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I've got this script:

```
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


global TEMP
for video in os.listdir(VIDEOS):
    ffmpeg = PATH + "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg"
    arg1 = " -v 0 -i "
    arg2 = VIDEOS + "/" + video
    arg3 = " -r 1 -f image2 "
    arg4 = TEMP + "/" + os.path.splitext(video)[0] + "-%d.jpg"
    subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4).wait()
```

that works perfectly on Windows (using ffmpeg.exe of course), but when I try to run it on Mac I got error:

```
  File "/Users/francesco/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 20, in Main
    subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4).wait()

  File "subprocess.pyc", line 710, in __init__

  File "subprocess.pyc", line 1327, in _execute_child

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried to print ffmpeg + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4 and paste it manually in the terminal, nothing happens, it just stuck, but if I try to copy manually all the printed arguments, it works.

Comment: Isn't the error obvious?

Comment: Nope because if i put the command manually on terminal it works, the file exists and the arguments are ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subprocess.Popen` requires list of strings, something like `[ffmpeg, arg1, ...]`.

This command fails on Linux:

```
subprocess.Popen("ls -la").wait()
```

while this one succeeds:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-la"]).wait()
```

Comment: PS: I know that you want to run it on Mac. I only wanted to show that the underlying operating system services differ on Windows and Linux/Unix/Mac.

Comment: Yes, it works on Windows too. This is the right way to provide subprocess options.

Comment: Bad idea starting writing my script on Windows. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a list of args and use `check_call` if you want to wait until the process returns:

```
from subprocess import check_call
for video in os.listdir(VIDEOS):
    check_call(["ffmpeg","-v", "0", "-i","{}/{}".format(VIDEOS,video), "-r", "1", "-f",
                "image2","{}/-%d.jpg".format(TEMP), os.path.splitext(video)[0]])
```

[check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) will raise a [CalledProcessError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) for any non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Python 3.7 and ffmpeg, both installed with brew. Just like for you, worked in terminal, but not as a (CRON) script. Turned out that the problem was not specifying the full PATH for ffmpeg, which in my case is "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3/bin/ffmpeg". So

[...]

```
import os

theCommand = "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3/bin/ffmpeg -i /Volumes/ramDisk/audio.mp4 -i /Volumes/ramDisk/video.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v copy /Volumes/ArchiveDisk/final.mp4" 
os.system(theCommand)
```